# Slickgrid not getting focus when clicking a non-editable cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid, slickgrid

I have a grid where several columns have editors specified and several columns are non-editable.

When I mouse out of the grid, the grid loses focus...which is great.

If I click back in on an editable cell, the grid gets focus back and all subsequent keyDown events are handled properly. However, if I click back into the grid on a non-editable cell, the grid does not gain focus and all subsequent keyDowns are not caught. This makes cell navigation very difficult.

Any pointers?

Comment: Are your non-editable columns set as `selectable` or `focusable`?

Comment: I have neither selectable or focusable set for these. Shouldn't they default to true?

Comment: Try setting `selectable: true, focusable: true` for the non-editable column definitions.

Comment: Just did. No change in behavior.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Unfortunately, it would be way too complicated (at least for me) to fit all of this into a fiddle. If I change one of the non-editable columns to editable, I get my desired behavior. I wander if I could create a hack with a dummy editor that doesn't actually change the value of the cell.

Comment: So my hack of creating a dummy editor worked... Can anyone thing of a more valid way to do this?